# How to manipulate position of Data label in highchart

Tags: jquery, charts, highcharts

I am using pie donut highchart ([view demo](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.9.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/pie-donut/)) and I want to define the data label position in the pie donut chart.

If I am using the demo chart with my data the position where values "Chrome", "MSIE", etc. are displayed get changed and comes out of my chart.

How can I fix the data label values position so that it may not change what so ever be the data percentage? The below code snippet maintains data label position:

```
series: [{
            name: 'Browsers',
            data: browserData,
            size: '60%',
            dataLabels: {
                formatter: function() {
                    return this.y > 5 ? this.point.name : null;
                },
                color: 'white',
                distance: -30
            }
```

But data label comes out of chart if data value is large and sometimes it disappear when data value is less.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what it is you want. Do you ALWAYS want to show the data label ("Chrome", etc.)? If so, how about `return this.point.name`? Or is it the length of the name that goes out of the chart?

Comment: The label disappears, because you have no enough space to print the label. Please attach your mockup, how chart should look like